# After upgrade to iOS 11, unable to use Touch ID

Tags: ios, touch-id

Our app support Touch ID. When user is using iOS10 and we save the login to keychain with Touch ID.

However, when the user upgraded to iOS11, the user is unable to retrieve saved Touch ID from iOS 10.

I have tested each iOS version and it works fine, only have issue with the upgrade.

It is hard to fix this without enough hardware and I can only upgrade once.

Code to show, inside viewDidLoad:

```html
let touchIdHelper = TouchIdHelper(promptMessage: viewModel.getPasswordReason)
        if !touchIdHelper.isDeviceTouchIdReady() {
            hideTouchIdComponents()
        } else {
            if self.viewModel.canLoginUsingTouchId {
                touchIdHelper.promptTouchId(completion: {
                    let decryptedPassword = self.viewModel.decryptedPassword
                    if decryptedPassword.characters.count > 0 {
                        self.updatePasswordAndLogin(decryptedPassword)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

And the store password function:

```html
func storePasswordForTouchIdLogin() -> Bool {
               
        let keychainHelper = KeychainHelper(dataCode: currentAccountId,
                                            encryptionKeyCode: touchIdEncryptionKey,
                                            data: currentPassword)
        return keychainHelper.encryptAndStore()
    }
```

And the decryption function:

```html
var decryptedPassword: String {
       
        let keychainHelper = KeychainHelper(dataCode: currentAccountId,
                                            encryptionKeyCode: touchIdEncryptionKey)
        return keychainHelper.readAndDecrypt()
    }
```

Anyone has encounter simulator issue? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Your TouchID implementation perhaps? My apps also support TouchID and no issues on upgrade. I am able to upgrade and downgrade many times (via saved SHSH2 blobs).

Comment: Thanks for reply, code snippet added.